# AWS Lambda with Apache Kafka Trigger returns "PROBLEM: Lambda internal error. Please contact Lambda customer support."

Tags: spring-cloud-function

I am using Spring Cloud Functions with Kafka Binder. My application **SpringcloudfuncApplication**.class
is pretty straightforward as can be seen below:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Log4j2
public class SpringcloudfuncApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringcloudfuncApplication.class, args); 
    }

    @Bean
    public Function<Message<String>, String> greeter() {
        return (input) -> {
            log.info("Hello {}", input.getPayload());
            return "Hello " + input.getPayload();
        };
    }

}
```

I am expecting a incoming **StringInput** then will return a greeting -> **Hello {StringInput}**

I have setup a self-managed Apache Kafka/Zookeeper on AWS EC2 instance with public access for testing purposes then updated my **application.yml** file:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: greeter
    stream:
      kafka:
        default:
          consumer:
            startOffset: earliest
        binder:
          brokers: ec2-13-212-236-60.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com:9092
      bindings:
        greeter-in-0:
          destination: topic-names
        greeter-out-0:
          destination: topic-greetings
```

Everything is working fine on my local setup pointing to this AWS EC2 with Kafka/Zookeeper. However, I am not able to make this work when I attempt to create a function in AWS Lambda with my shaded jar then added Apache Kafka for trigger. I have followed this [AWS Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-self-hosted-apache-kafka-as-an-event-source-for-aws-lambda/) in setting up AWS Lambda with self-hosted Kafka as an Event source.

Take note that doing a AWS Lambda test by sending a string (using hello-world template) my function works. But adding a Kafka trigger gives me below error:

[Last processing result: PROBLEM: Lambda internal error. Please contact Lambda customer support.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UkUh.png)

Maven dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-function-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-function-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-function-adapter-aws</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Maven build plugin for shaded JAR:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
           <configuration>
               <skip>true</skip>
           </configuration>
       </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
               <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot.experimental</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-thin-layout</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring-boot-thin-layout.version}</version>
               </dependency>
           </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                <shadedClassifierName>aws</shadedClassifierName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Thank you in advance! Cheers!

Comment: Your error seems to be specific to the environment you are running at `Last processing result: PROBLEM: Lambda internal error. Please contact Lambda customer support.`. At least at the moment there is no indication that anything in Spring is causing it. Perhaps you can contact "contact Lambda customer support' to get more information?

Comment: Hi @OlegZhurakousky noted and thank you for your quick response (I'm a big fan of your works). Anyways, I would like to add the tag of äws lambda" but it looks I am not yet qualified for such. Thanks again. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the main issue is I have used public subnet on my EC2 instance with Apache Kafka/Zookeeper thus I have declared a public DNS on the AWS Lambda trigger - Apache Kafka Bootsrap servers. Now, I got it working by going thru again [this reference](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-self-hosted-apache-kafka-as-an-event-source-for-aws-lambda/) but instead of using a NAT gateway I have setup a [NAT Instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_NAT_Instance.html#nat-instance-ami) for better costing. I am now getting OK on the processing results.

```
Apache Kafka: Endpoints: [ip-10-0-1-199.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal:9092] (Enabled)
Details
Batch size: 100
Last processing result: OK
selfManagedEventSource:
```

Looking into the AWS CloudWatch logs, I am now seeing these logs:

```
2021-03-02 12:00:45.912  INFO 8 --- [           main] o.s.c.f.a.aws.CustomRuntimeEventLoop     : Located function greeter
2021-03-02 12:00:45.918  INFO 8 --- [           main] c.j.s.s.SpringcloudfuncApplication       : Hello {
    "eventSource": "SelfManagedKafka",
    "bootstrapServers": "ip-10-0-1-199.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal:9092",
    "records": {
        "topic-names-0": [
            {
                "topic": "topic-names",
                "partition": 0,
                "offset": 13,
                "timestamp": 1614686444377,
                "timestampType": "CREATE_TIME",
                "value": "SnVuIEtpbmc="
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And this goes to my next question, my String message produced on the topic is "Jun King" but the message returned to me is a JSON payload with my expected value encoded into Base64. I have tried to decode "SnVuIEtpbmc=" using this [Online Base64Decoder](https://www.base64decode.org/) which indeed return my actual message "Jun King".

I can process this within the code but would that make my function AWS-aware? and would have to traverse it. Thank you again in advance. Cheers!